# Compiler Sample Program of MSQUIC GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw, quic

I am trying to compile and run the sample program of msquic. I downloaded the openssl latest release of msquic quic and added to my project folder.

##### My Folder Structure

```
-sample.c
-msquic
  -bin
    -msquic.dll
    -msquic.pdb
  -include
    -msquic_winuser.h
    -msquic.h
  -lib
    -msquic.lib
```

##### I used the following to compile

```
g++ sample.c -I msquic/include -L msquic/lib -o main.exe
```

##### I got the following errors plus more..

```
In file included from sample.c:47:
msquic/include/msquic.h:763:10: warning: 'cdecl' attribute only applies to function types [-Wattributes]
  763 |     _In_ _Pre_defensive_ HQUIC Handle,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
msquic/include/msquic.h:762:13: error: typedef 'QUIC_SET_CONTEXT_FN' is initialized (use 'decltype' instead)
  762 | (QUIC_API * QUIC_SET_CONTEXT_FN)(
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
msquic/include/msquic.h:763:10: error: '_Pre_defensive_' was not declared in this scope
  763 |     _In_ _Pre_defensive_ HQUIC Handle,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.... a lot more similar errors
```

I think I am not compiling the code in the proper way. Suggest the correct way.

#### Resources:

**msquic-repo:** https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/

**sample.c:** https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/blob/main/src/tools/sample/sample.c

**msquic (release):** https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/releases/tag/v2.2.2, https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/releases/download/v2.2.2/msquic_windows_x64_Release_openssl.zip

###### More information about my system:

Windows 11 Home, MinGW g++ 12.2.0 compiler

Comment: Is MSQUIC intended to be compiled with MSVC (rather than mingw)?

Answer (score 1):

As another person stated above, you either should compile windows executable using MSVC and link it against windows version of msquic lib (dll/lib) OR you compile Linux executable (using g++) and link it against msquic lib built specifically for Linux (.so library)

You can build & install msquic as described here : https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/blob/main/docs/BUILD.md

On Linux, the easiest way to build and install was using vcpkg:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh #.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat(for windows)
./vcpkg integrate install
./vcpkg install ms-quic
```

Then you compile your sample like this:

```
g++ -I/root/projects/vcpkg/packages/ms-quic_x64-linux/include/ ./sample2.c  -lmsquic -L/root/projects/vcpkg/packages/ms-quic_x64-linux/lib
```

Also note that there are no blank spaces coming after -I and -L

Hope this helps ...